# eliminate or draw over last UITableView separator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView with default (light gray) separator lines.

The last row/cell in my table has a dark background.  When scrolled all the way into view, the UITableView is drawing one last separator line below this last row, and it looks bad.  I'd rather it not be there, or at least in the same color as my last cell's background.

I know the trick for setting a zero-sized footer to eliminate the "fake" rows and separators.  That isn't working for this.

Any ideas?  I'd rather not disable (or make transparent) separators all together and draw them myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution was to just cover up the bottom of the tableview.  In my case, I extended the tableview a pixel down behind the toolbar at the bottom of my view.